# Aurelia ValidationRules is not triggering

Tags: javascript, aurelia

am new to Aurelia Js and i need to do validate login form (required and emial) property. Here i used **aurelia-validation** plugin. My code below,
**login.js**

```
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
import {
    ValidationRules
} from 'aurelia-validation';

export class login{
    static inject() { return [Router]; }
    attached(){
    }
}
ValidationRules
    .ensure('login.emial').required()
    .withMessage(`\${$displayName} cannot be blank.`);
 `
```

i don't know how to trigger this and show error message.

**main.js**

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
export function configure(aurelia) {
aurelia.use
    .defaultBindingLanguage()
    .defaultResources()
    .developmentLogging()
    .router()
    .history()
    .eventAggregator()
    .plugin("aurelia-materialize-css")
    .plugin('aurelia-validation')
;
aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
```

}
**HTML**

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="validate" value.bind="login.emial">
```

Answer (score 1):

login.js

```
import {ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validation';

export class Login{
  email = '';
}

ValidationRules
  .ensure('email').required();
```

login.html

```
<template>
  <input value.bind="email & validate">
</template>
```

- https://gist.run/?id=381fdb1a4b0865a4c25026187db865ce
- https://gist.run/?id=1d612b3ae341c7e9c12113e1771988e7

Answer (score 1):

From the above **Jeremy Danyow** answer, Must and should you have to provide **form-group** class on top of input fields like below code. then only validation will work otherwise it will not work.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <input value.bind="email & validate">
 </div>
```